# Deactivate Viber account on different device

Tags: viber-messenger, samsung-galaxy-tab-3

As I lost the access code that Viber sent to me, I cannot sign in my Viber account. I signed in on another device. Now, I want to deactivate the account, so that the device holder cannot get my messages and conversations.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to Viber's official guide on how to [Deactivate your Viber account (Mobile)](https://support.viber.com/customer/portal/articles/1335420-deactivate-your-viber-account-mobile-):

> 1. Open Viber
> 2. Enter the More Options menu
> 3. Select Settings
> 4. Select Privacy
> 5. Select Deactivate Account
>
> Deactivation can only take place within the application. If you have
>   uninstalled Viber and would like to deactivate your account, you will
>   need to re-install Viber in order to do so.